# Best way to embed exact output from an URL into a JSP

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, liferay

I am working with Liferay and I need to show a preview of HTML output of an URL as an embeded window in a JSP view. I am assessing different possibilities.

1. Store somewhat the interface to preview as a screenshot image and show it as an embeded image. Good thing is that formatting would be totally the same.
2. Parse URL output stream with a BufferedReader and clean all html, scripting, body tags with indexOf. Embed images as `cid:`
3. Some kind of include, jsp:include or liferay-util:include form direct URL of downloaded temporal HTML output
4. Any JQuery AJAX $().html() kind of solution
5. Any HTML-level solution in iframe, applet, frame, appletwindow or whatever if it exists

What do you think is the best or recommended way: simplest, reliable and exact looking? Any code or reference?

And in case I had to send it as a JavaMail Message content into an email direction?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be done client-side, in Javascript, or even via iframes. Either put the iframes in the page directly, or have javascript code that generates the iframes, and point the iframes at the URL to be previewed. Keep it simple.